# Estimating the amount of space products take up in the database

Tags: product, database, ce-1.9.0.1

I currently have 10,263 items in my database. All of the products contain the same amount of information. Is there a way I can estimate the size of my database if I added another 70,000 products?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's an approach you could use:

1. Backup and copy your database.
2. Create a copy of the Magento site, connecting it to the new database copy.
3. Measure how large the database is.
4. Delete all the products from the copy.  **Don't do this on your live site!**
5. Measure how large the database is.

The difference between #3 and #5 will tell you how much storage those 10,263 products took up.  Multiply that by 6 to estimate the additional storage required to add the ~60,000 new products.